# Custom Header Information in Postfix Bounce Header

Tags: email, postfix-mta, email-bounces

I am trying to keep the custom header information in a bounce message. I am using postfix 3.4.14

If the message is send to the original destination, the custom header is complete:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Disposition: inline
custom_header: Example
```

In the bounce message, the custom header information is missing. Is there any option to configure this?